# Durandal widgets inner function scope and context

Tags: javascript, durandal, syncfusion

I have durandal widget and two syncfusion buttons:

**view.html**

```
<div class="group-btn-container">            
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="ejToggleButton: toggleButtonNo" />
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="ejToggleButton: toggleButtonYes" />
</div>
```

**viewmodel.js**

```
define(['knockout', 'jquery','web/ej.togglebutton.min', 'common/ej.widget.ko.min'], function (ko, $) {

    var ctor = function () { };

    ctor.prototype.activate = function (settings) {
        self = this;

        var toggleBtnYes = {         
            toggleState: ko.observable(false),
            click: function (args) {
                self.toggleButtonNo.buttonOptions.toggleState(false);
                args.model.toggleState(true);
            }
        }
        self.toggleButtonYes = toggleBtnYes;

        var toggleBtnNo = {          
            toggleState: ko.observable(true),
            click: function (args) {
                self.toggleButtonYes.buttonOptions.toggleState(false);
                args.model.toggleState(true);
            }
        }
        self.toggleButtonNo = toggleBtnNo;
    };
    return ctor;
});
```

Two buttons 'Yes' and 'No', should work like radio buttons, when one is turned on, another should be turned off.

Q1: I have a problem with viewodel context or scope.
Inside click function I do not see 'self', actually self is always some another widget because in one loop I render couple widgets, I do not know why self is not my function ctor ?

Q2: Also when I want to approach to object 'toggleBtnNo' or 'toggleBtnYes' directly from click function, they are not defined. Why I cannot see the objects from global function ctor in my inner, 'click' function?

I just do not know how to approach to the button (on one or other way) from my click function how I can change it state ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the worst mistake ever. I was looking at that million times and did not notice. I am ashamed.

I did not put 'var' in front of self.

```
self = this;
```

should be:

```
var self = this;
```

It caused that self goes to the global scope and every time some other widget overwrites value of self.

Answer (score 0):

From the code snippet you have provided, it seems you are trying to update the toggleButton’s state by **assigning values to the model**. With this, the model values is just assigned and is **not reflected** in ToggleButton control.

Rather, for the ToggleButton control to be updated, you need to update the value in the observable variable **(self.toggleButtonNo.toggleState)** in the module and call ko.applyBindings method, so that the model values will be updated the ToggleButton control.

Please refer the code snippet provided below.

**HTML**

```
<input id="yes" type="checkbox" data-bind="ejToggleButton: {toggleState: toggleButtonYes.toggleState , defaultText: settings.defaultText, activeText: settings.activeText, click: toggleButtonYes.click}" />

<input id="no" type="checkbox" data-bind="ejToggleButton: {toggleState: toggleButtonNo.toggleState, defaultText: settings.defaultText, activeText: settings.activeText, click: toggleButtonNo.click}" />
```

**Script**

```
define('mo1', ['knockout', 'jquery'], function (ko, $) {

        return function () {
            self = this;
            self.settings = {
                defaultText: "No",
                activeText: "Yes",
            };
            var toggleBtnYes = {
                toggleState: ko.observable(true),
                click: function (args) {
                    self.toggleButtonNo.toggleState(false);
                    self.toggleButtonYes.toggleState(true);
                    ko.applyBindings(self);
                }
            }
            self.toggleButtonYes = toggleBtnYes;

            var toggleBtnNo = {

                toggleState: ko.observable(false),
                click: function (args) {
                    self.toggleButtonYes.toggleState(false);
                    self.toggleButtonNo.toggleState(true);
                    ko.applyBindings(self);
                }
            }
            self.toggleButtonNo = toggleBtnNo;
        };
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. You are right I made mistake in knockout, did not do applyBindings. But my problem that self/this is not self of my function then someone else is still here. I am not sure but that is Durandal question. Maybe I did not construct 'ctor' function properly. I have a problem also in your example with that.